# "Opposite" of Porter Stemmer algorithm?

Tags: php, porter-stemmer

I'm looking for some way of performing the opposite of a [Porter Stemmer algorithm](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/), i.e. the string "search" would return an array "searches, searched, searching etc.."

Does something like this exist already (pref in php)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What should it return for "happy"? Or "day"?

Comment: Just plurals I would guess, although it would be nice to do "happiness" etc, that would probably involve doing a dictionary lookup though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the direction that you're looking to go but I would grab a file of dictionary words (Mac and nix machines usually have one at `/usr/share/dict/words`) and load it into an easily searched storage mechanism.

Next, I'd compile a list of [suffixes](http://www.learnthat.org/vocabulary/pages/view/suffix.html) and program in the [rules applied to suffixes](http://www.say-it-in-english.com/SomeRules.html).

In regard to the actual question asked I have not found anything that exists like this already.

Comment: Thanks for the links, looks like I'm going to have to build something myself then! :S