# Is there a tool to obtain all get all derivatives of a word in PHP?

Tags: php, cpu-word, porter-stemmer

I need to input "face" and get "facial, faces, faced, facing, facer, faceable" etc.

I've come across some ineffective programs which do the opposite, such as SNOWBALL and a couple of Porter Stemming PHP scripts which don't seem to work.

I'm beginning to think I may have to write this script - But, I thought I'd check to see if somebody has already been there/done that.

Comment: the best way is to use a dictionary

Comment: A porter stemmer algorithm would help you reduce complex words to their base stem (e.g. "facial" to "face") but I don't know about branching out to derivative based on that.  You would need quite a large database of words, I think.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Opposite" of Porter Stemmer algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207116/opposite-of-porter-stemmer-algorithm)

Comment: There is an exact duplicate of this question at the top of the "Related" questions list just to the right. This would also have appeared whilst you wrote your question.

Comment: So, apparently is doesn't exist! Well - time to get to work. The reverse can be accomplished with a vast dictionary database and an extensive library of lexicographical rules, prefixes, endings etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. That question didn't turn up in search results. Well, I'll get back when I've found a solution - The other question does not contain a solution.

Comment: no use a webservice rather than try to create that database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be very hard to simply find an algorithm to find the different way a word can be written like that.

You can use a [dictionary webservice](http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx) instead that have all the words available already

Comment: Cool I don't quite understand the mechanics of the dic websvc but it look promising

Comment: sadly none of the dictionary webservices seem to have "derived forms" as a function - The closest I've found is a regular website `http://www.wordwebonline.com` which contains 'derived forms' at the bottom. But it doesn't include adverbs or other forms.

Comment: I've found one solution - You can place your word list in Excel, in my case 14,000 words. Sort your list with the filter/contains, does not contain etc. Separate words into columns, find/replace for "es" and "s" and "ed" etc. Then write a script to check all words against a large dictionary and keep only the ones which exist.